# PHP and MySQL Project Pay

Tags: php, mysql, project

Someone asked me to design a database and implement it using MySQL. Additionally, I am also asked to write PHP scripts so that one can do some "simple" data analysis with the data inside MySQL. It is not very complicated. It is like a school database and I will have to write programs that will retrieve all the classes that a student has taken and stuff like that.

I am wondering how much I should charge for this kind of project.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366338/how-much-does-website-development-cost-nowadays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work out time and charge a rate that you think it will cost you. Freelance rates vary hugley by location and skill level. Also what about the clients budget? Lots of factors will play a part

Also google a little, there is plenty of data out there.

http://www.bytestart.co.uk/content/contractors/contractor-guides/it-contractor-market-rates.shtml

Also a useful answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806298/short-contract-pay-rates-for-programmers-in-the-uk

Comment: I am still a student and my client doesnt have that much budget for this project. That's why they want me to do it.

Comment: You have answered the question then. Work with what budget is available.

Comment: Or don't work at all if it's not worth the interference with your studying. "An investment in yourself always pays the best interest!" ... Benjamin Franklin

Comment: @adamantinex - If you are happy with the answer please select one (Click the green tick).